# Check boxes are not aligned properly. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

You can see improper alignment of the check boxes as seen in the attached image. I tried various ways to fix but nothing seems to work. Can you please point out my mistake? I want them in proper alignment no matter how big the words are, as you can see the alignment currently depends upon the word size.

[image]

**The Code:**

```css
.checkbox {
  font: 15px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 15px;
  margin-right: 250px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #0088cc;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox:before {
  content: "\2713";
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="Option" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" for="Option" style="margin-left: 102px;">Wedding Photography</label>
  <input id="option2" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" for="option2">Portfolio</label>
  <input id="option3" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" for="option3">Product Photography</label>
  <input id="option4" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" for="option4">Festive Photography</label>
</form>
<form>
  <input id="option5" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" style="margin-left: 102px;" for="option5">Baby Photography</label>
  <input id="option6" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" for="option6">Animal Photography</label>
  <input id="option7" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" for="option7">Event Photography</label>
  <input id="option8" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" for="option8">Mobile Photography</label>
</form>
<form>
  <input id="option9" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" style="margin-left: 102px;" for="option9">Animals Photoshoot</label>
  <input id="option10" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" for="option10">Flim Making</label>
  <input id="option11" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" for="option11">Corporate Photography</label>
  <input id="option12" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox" for="option12">Video Services</label>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried with %, it gets messey so I used px.

Comment: So simply use table structure as posted by @ali786;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with this below css will may resolve issue.

```
.checkbox {
  font: 15px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 15px;
  //margin-right: 50px;
  line-height: 18px;
  width : 23%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove margin, and add width **20%**.

```
.checkbox {
    font: 15px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 18px;
    float: left;
}
```